# Dual 555 siren circuit keeps burning 555 ICs, but why?

Tags: 555

I've found the following circuit online, which creates a siren sound from two 555 ICs.
[image: Dual 555 siren circuit]
Please note:

- the 1ohm resistors were added because Falstad otherwise assumes that a capacitor without resistor is a short circuit
- the 4.7k and 100k resistors are variable resistors (for which there is no symbol in Falstad afaik)
- there is no symbol for a speaker, so I used the closest resistor value possible, which is the 8.2ohm resistor

After building the circuit, I found out the second 555 IC was running quite hot. Also, it didn't produce a sound. After looking at similar circuits it struck me as odd that the control pin from the second IC gets driven from the trigger/threshold connection from the first, so I changed it: it is now driven from the output of IC one (as I expected it to be). The circuit now procudes a sound.

However, I've burnt through three 555 ICs so far. As soon as the 100k reached 0ohm, the IC starts to heat up rapidly (.2° per second as monitored), and the chip is damaged at a temperature around 50°-60°. I suspect it's a lot hotter inside, though.

My guess was that the 8.2ohm speaker was the culprit, that the 555 was driving it with too much current, so I removed the capacitor and speaker, connected the output to an amplifier, and connected the speaker to an amplifier. Also, the 100k variable resistor was changed to a fixed 1k resistor.

Everything now works as expected, but still the 555 warms up at about .1° per minute (and keeps climbing).

My PSU is set to 12V with a current limit of .3A, but it never rises above 0.21A.

So I'm stuck with some questions:

1. Why did the second IC burn out in the first place?
2. Why does the temperature keep rising in the final situation?
3. If the total energy consumption is only 0.21A max, where does the energy come from to burn the 555?

Any and all ideas are very welcome!

Comment: You may find a 555 isn't spec'ed to drive an 8 ohm load. Check its datasheet for max output current rating.

Comment: @user_1818839 That's what I though, which is why I connected the output to an amplifier, but even then the chip still heats up. Slowly, and a lot slower than before, but the temperature still keeps rising.

Comment: I would expect the Ctl pin of the second 555 to be driven from the Trigger pin of the first 555 as shown in your diagram and, if I understand correctly, as you originally had it connected. The Ctl pin of the second 555 would then be driven by the near triangle wave at the top of the 47uF capacitor which limits at Vcc/3 and 2Vcc/3. The idea is to ramp up and down the Ctl pin in order to slowly modulate the output frequency of the 2nd 555 to create the more slowly changing siren sound.

Comment: Is it still burning out?

Comment: It is not burning out, but the temperature still keeps rising. A lot slower than before, but it is still rising and I'm not risking any more chips to find out if it'll reach the limit.